# Read custom input file(ldif) type/format in GCP DatafLow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have ldif extension file from LDAP system. I am able to easily parse this in python and extract required data from file and insert into SQL server. My sample python looks like below.

```
import os
from ldif3 import LDIFParser
import pymssql

parser = LDIFParser(open('temp.ldiff', 'rb'))

def return_dictionary_element_if_present(dict_entry, element):
    if dict_entry.get(element):
        return dict_entry.get(element)[0]
    return ''   

def add_new_user():
    for dn, entry in parser.parse():
        dict_entry = dict(entry)
        email = return_dictionary_element_if_present(dict_entry,'email')
        password = return_dictionary_element_if_present(dict_entry,'password')
        #some code to insert into SQL server
add_new_user()
```

But when i am looking to convert this to dataflow, iam unable to understand what and where to modify. My Data flow code looks something like below

```
class sqlserverwriteDoFn(beam.DoFn):
    #insert statement 


class CreateEntities(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        #figure out how to return dictionary if parsed correctly
        return [{"email": email, "password": password}]


def dataflow(input_file, pipeline_options):
    print("starting")
    options = GoogleCloudOptions.from_dictionary(pipeline_options)
    with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
        (p | 'Reading Ldif data from GCS' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(input_file)
           | 'Create entities' >> beam.ParDo(CreateEntities())
           | 'Insert data to SQLSERVER' >> beam.ParDo(sqlserverwriteDoFn(pipeline_options['project']))
         )
```

I think ReadFromText converts each line into pcollection which in my case does not work. Sample ldif file looks like this

```
dn: uid=12345,ab=users,xy=random
phone: 111
address: someaddress
email: true
username:abc
password:abc


dn: uid=12345,ab=users,xy=random
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: top
phone: 111
address: someaddress
email: true
username:abcd
password:abcd
```

Any ideas is really appreciated as I am looking to import 50 million user names and passwords from LDIF file and definitely simple python for loop can not be scaled.

**[Edit1] As per comments, modified code and getting some other error**

```
def return_dictionary_element_if_present(dict_entry, element):
    if dict_entry.get(element):
        return dict_entry.get(element)[0]
    return ''

class CreateEntities(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, file):
        parser = LDIFParser(open(file, 'rb'))
        arr=[]
        for dn, entry in parser.parse():
            dict1 ={}
            dict_entry = dict(entry)
            email = return_dictionary_element_if_present(dict_entry,'email')
            password = return_dictionary_element_if_present(dict_entry,'password')
            dict1['email'] = email
            dict1['password'] = password
            arr.append(dict1)
        return arr


def dataflow(pipeline_options):
    print("starting")
    options = GoogleCloudOptions.from_dictionary(pipeline_options)
    with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
        (p | 'Reading data from GCS' >> MatchFiles(file_pattern="temp.ldiff")
           | 'file match' >> ReadMatches()
           | 'Create entities' >> beam.ParDo(CreateEntities())
           | 'print to screen' >> beam.Map(print)
         )
```

Getting follwoing error

```
  File "dataflow.py", line 26, in process
    parser = LDIFParser(open(file, 'rb'))
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not ReadableFile [while running 'Create entities']
```

**Edit2**
changed one line of python code as below

```
parser = LDIFParser(file)
```

Got this error

```
  File "dataflow.py", line 28, in process
    for dn, entry in parser.parse():
  File "C:\Users\sande\anaconda3\envs\saopaulo\lib\site-packages\ldif3.py", line 383, in parse
    for block in self._iter_blocks():
  File "C:\Users\sande\anaconda3\envs\saopaulo\lib\site-packages\ldif3.py", line 282, in _iter_blocks
    for line in self._iter_unfolded_lines():
  File "C:\Users\sande\anaconda3\envs\saopaulo\lib\site-packages\ldif3.py", line 263, in _iter_unfolded_lines
    line = self._input_file.readline()
AttributeError: 'ReadableFile' object has no attribute 'readline' [while running 'Create entities']
```

How should i change my code so that error is resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, TextIO in the Python SDK uses newline as the delimiter to separate elements. So each element produced is a single line of the input file.

In your original code you already have a parser that can read LDIF files. You can use that in your pipeline via a [ParDo transform](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#pardo). I would recommend beginning with [FileIO](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.30.0/apache_beam.io.fileio.html) to create a PCollection of LDIF files, and then use those as input to your own ParDo which parses those files and outputs your records. Note that you will likely want to read on [managing Beam Python dependencies](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/) if you want to use the existing parser on Dataflow, as your Dataflow worker will need access to that dependency.

Comment: thanks for answering question. I have updated question  based on your suggestions and now iam getting different error. Can you please help me debug this?

Comment: @sandeep007 I recommend taking a read through the code for [ReadableFile](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.30.0/_modules/apache_beam/io/fileio.html#ReadableFile) (the output type of ReadMatches). I think what you probably need is `LDIFParser(file.open())`.

Comment: Thankyou Daniel for your time and help. Its working now. I am able to print on screen.